# Split string on space if the word is longer than 2 character

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble to find the exact formula to split the string on space if the word is longer than 2 character.

```
$str = 'test 1 vitamin d3 test 2';

$str_parts = preg_split('#(?:\s+|(vitamin [cde]))#', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

var_export($str_parts);
```

An ideal output would be:

`['test 1', 'vitamin d3', 'test 2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in `split`:

```
\h+(?=\w{3})
```

Which matches 1+ whitespaces if there is a word with at least 3 characters afterwards using a positive lookahead.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V17Xuo/1)

**Code:**

```sh
$str = 'test 1 vitamin d3 test 2';
$str_parts = preg_split('/\h+(?=\w{3})/', $str);
print_r($str_parts);
```

**Output:**

```sh
Array
(
    [0] => test 1
    [1] => vitamin d3
    [2] => test 2
)
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava for your help this is I exactly I was looking for. Also thank you for @wiktor-stribiżew either way could be perfect but since I was looking for preg_split version I accepted anubhava answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reverse logic and *extract* sequences of a 3 or more letter word followed with 1-2 letter words:

```php
preg_match_all('~\b\w{3,}(?:\W+\w{1,2})*\b~', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bwRFex/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w{3,}` - three or more word chars
- `(?:\W+\w{1,2})*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
  - `\w{1,2}` - one to two word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary